# How do I conditionally expand the types of a container from within a variadic template?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create a wrapper for variant that allows me to wrap a bunch of types passed in another type, and put them into the variant. How would I expand a tuple's types and place them into the variant conditionally based on whether the type is a container?

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper
{};

template <typename>
struct has_expandable_types : std::false_type
{
};

template <template <typename...> class T, typename... Args>
struct has_expandable_types<T<Args...>> : std::true_type
{
};

template <template <typename> class T, typename... Types>
struct Variant_wrapper;
template <template <typename> class T, typename U, typename... Types>
struct Variant_wrapper_expanded;

template <template <typename> class T, typename... Types>
struct Variant_wrapper : std::variant<T<Types>...>
{
};

template <template <typename> class T, template <typename...> class U, typename... UTypes>
struct Variant_wrapper_expanded <T, U<UTypes...>> : Variant_wrapper<T, UTypes...>
{
};

using Types = std::tuple<int, float>;

int main()
{
    //std::variant< Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float> >, OK
    Variant_wrapper<Wrapper, int, float> var; 

    //std::variant< Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float> >, OK
    Variant_wrapper_expanded<Wrapper, Types> var2;

    //std::variant< Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float> >, NOT OK
    // EXPECTED std::variant< Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float>, Wrapper<double> >
    //can't capture a second parameter pack?
    Variant_wrapper_expanded<Wrapper, Types, double> var3;
}
```

The ideal usage would be something like

```
//produces std::variant< Wrapper<std::string>, Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float>, Wrapper<double> >
Variant_wrapper<Wrapper, std::string, Types, double> var;
```

1. In the var3 example, it doesn't look like I can have a second parameter pack to capture the remaining types after the tuple even though UTypes is only for the container types. How can I capture the remaining types?
2. Passing a tuple type to `Variant_wrapper` wraps the entire tuple but I'd like to be able to expand the held types and insert them into the variant instead. How would I do the expansion?

Comment: Notice that `std::string` is actually `std::basic_string<..>` so would match with your `U<UTypes...>`...

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

I noticed the additional requirement that the `std::tuple` argument could be in any position. The following allows for passing types or types wrapped with `std::tuple` as template parameters in any order. It only requires one more specialization than the original method.

There are four specializations to handle:

- The only template parameter is a `std::tuple`
- The first template parameter is not a `std::tuple`
- The first template parameter is a `std::tuple` but the second is not
- The first and second template parameters are `std::tuple`

The base case is a single `std::tuple` template parameter. This is easily translated to the wrapped `std::variant`. All of the other cases recurse to each other or the base case.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <variant>

template<template<class> class T, class... Ts>
struct variant_wrapper_impl;

// The base case is that all types come packaged in a single tuple.
template<template<class> class T, class... Ts>
struct variant_wrapper_impl<T, std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    using type = std::variant<T<Ts>...>;
};

// The first type is not a tuple.
template<template<class> class T, class U, class... Us>
struct variant_wrapper_impl<T, U, Us...> {
    using type = typename variant_wrapper_impl<T, std::tuple<U>, Us...>::type;
};

// The first type is a tuple and the second type is not a tuple.
template<template<class> class T, class... Ts, class U, class... Us>
struct variant_wrapper_impl<T, std::tuple<Ts...>, U, Us...> {
    using type = typename variant_wrapper_impl<T, std::tuple<Ts..., U>, Us...>::type;
};

// The first type is a tuple and the second type is a tuple.
template<template<class> class T, class... Ts, class... Us, class... Ws>
struct variant_wrapper_impl<T, std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Us...>, Ws...> {
    using type = typename variant_wrapper_impl<T, std::tuple<Ts..., Us...>, Ws...>::type;
};

template<template<class> class T, class... Ts>
using variant_wrapper_t = typename variant_wrapper_impl<T, Ts...>::type;

template<class T>
class Wrapper {
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<variant_wrapper_t<Wrapper, int, float>,
              std::variant<Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float>>>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<variant_wrapper_t<Wrapper, std::tuple<int, float>>,
              std::variant<Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float>>>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<variant_wrapper_t<Wrapper, std::tuple<int, float>, double>,
              std::variant<Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float>, Wrapper<double>>>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<variant_wrapper_t<Wrapper, char, std::tuple<int, float>, double>,
              std::variant<Wrapper<char>, Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float>, Wrapper<double>>>);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

**End Update**

I think the following satisfies your requirements. The key idea is the partial specializations of `variant_wrapper_imp` to handle the unwrapping of the tuple sub-types.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <variant>

template<template<class> class T, class... Ts>
struct variant_wrapper_impl;

// The simple case: W, int, float -> variant<W<int>, W<float>>
template<template<class> class T, class... Ts>
struct variant_wrapper_impl {
    using type = std::variant<T<Ts>...>;
};

// The tuple case: W, tuple<int, float> -> variant<W<int>, W<float>>
//
// We use the pattern matching of partial specialization to extract
// the tuple sub-types into Ts...
template<template<class> class T, class... Ts>
struct variant_wrapper_impl<T, std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    using type = std::variant<T<Ts>...>;
};

// The tuple+ case: W, tuple<int, float>, double -> variant<W<int>, W<float>, W<double>>
//
// We again use the pattern matching of partial specialization to
// extract the tuple sub-types into Ts.. and then recurse to the simple case.
template<template<class> class T, class... Ts, class... Us>
struct variant_wrapper_impl<T, std::tuple<Ts...>, Us...> {
    using type = typename variant_wrapper_impl<T, Ts..., Us...>::type;
};

template<template<class> class T, class... Ts>
using variant_wrapper_t = typename variant_wrapper_impl<T, Ts...>::type;

template<class T>
class Wrapper {
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<variant_wrapper_t<Wrapper, int, float>,
              std::variant<Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float>>>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<variant_wrapper_t<Wrapper, std::tuple<int, float>>,
              std::variant<Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float>>>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<variant_wrapper_t<Wrapper, std::tuple<int, float>, double>,
              std::variant<Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<float>, Wrapper<double>>>);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does satisfy what I'm looking for since I only have one tuple to pass in, but I'd also like a more generic solution that works with multiple tuples, or tuples that can exist at different positions (see the ideal usage in the OP). It looks like for this example they can only exist as the first argument. Could you provide an example of how that would look?

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that requirement on my first reading. I updated the answer to be more general.

Answer (score 2):

With C++17 CTAD, you might do:

```
// Tuple_expander<A, std::tuple<B, C>, D>::type -> std::tuple<A, B, C, D> 
template <typename... Ts>
struct Tuple_expander
{
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::tuple{std::declval<Ts>()}...));
// trick is here:
// std::tuple{std::tuple{..}} use copy constructor
// std::tuple{..} wrap the type in a tuple.
};

// The mapping/transformation of the (flat) tuple
template <template <typename> class C, typename T> struct TupleToVariantWrapper;

template <template <typename> class C, typename... Ts>
struct TupleToVariantWrapper<C, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::variant<C<Ts>...>;
};

// No real changes.
template <template <typename> class C, typename... Ts>
struct Variant_wrapper
{
    using type = std::variant<C<Ts>...>;
};

template <template <typename> class C, typename... Ts>
struct Variant_wrapper_expanded
{
    using type = typename TupleToVariantWrapper<C, typename Tuple_expander<Ts...>::type>::type;
};
```

(I use `::type` instead of inheritance)

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mxch59jh9)

Answer (score 1):

How about one more parameter pack in the specialization arguments:

```
template<template<typename> class T,
         template <typename...> class U,
         typename... UTypes,
         typename... Types>

struct Variant_wrapper_expanded<
               T
               U<UTypes...>,
               Types...> : 
       Variant_wrapper<T,
                       UTypes...,
                       Types...> {};
```

You are gonna need at least C++17 for this to compile.

Comment: I did try this and didn't realize the second parameter pack needed to be in the specialization so thanks for that. However this has its limitations that the container needs to be the first argument, and there can only be one of them. Ideally I'd like a more generic solution that would handle other cases

Comment: Unfortunately, parameter packs have limitations. For the second part of your question, the syntax will become unreadable. You'll need to group the arguments between an extra pair of broken braces using a helper `typelist` template, which is not quite different from directly using `std::tuple`.

Comment: `Variant_wrapper_expanded<tuple1, tuple2, tuple3>` or alternatively `Variant_wrapper_expanded<type_list<left_args...>, middle_tuple, type_list<right_args...>>`