# How best to write the base case of this recursive template?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a template function that has this behavior:

```
// count_template_params<>()               == 0
// count_template_params<int>()            == 1
// count_template_params<int, int>()       == 2
// count_template_params<int, int, int>()  == 3
// etc...
```

This is the closest I've been able to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int DUMMY>
constexpr int count_template_params() {
    return 0;
}

template<int DUMMY, class T, class... SS>
constexpr int count_template_params() {
    return 1 + count_template_params<DUMMY, SS...>();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int count = count_template_params<0, int, int, int, int>();
    std::cout << "Count=" << count << std::endl;
}
```

That works, it prints '4' as expected.  However, it has the ugly DUMMY parameter.  If I remove the dummy parameter, the compiler mistakes the recursion base case for template specialization.  Is there a way to do this that doesn't have the DUMMY parameter?

Comment: Jup: `template<class...Args> constexpr int count_template_params() { return sizeof...(Args); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76203301/1202808) mentions, this particular example can be solved with `sizeof...()` In fact, it cannot be solved with recursion because you are using a function template which does not allow for partial specialization.

There are, however, still many times when recursion is the best solution for working with meta-programming and templates (e.g. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76200586/1202808)). The canonical approach for your particular example would be something like the following using `struct` which allows for the necessary partial specialization.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<class... Ts>
struct count;

template<>
struct count<> {
    static constexpr auto value = 0;
};

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct count<T, Ts...> {
    static constexpr auto value = 1 + count<Ts...>::value;
};

template<class... Ts>
inline constexpr auto count_v = count<Ts...>::value;

static_assert(count_v<> == 0);
static_assert(count_v<int> == 1);
static_assert(count_v<int,int> == 2);
static_assert(count_v<int,int,int> == 3);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

A typical maneuver is to accept template arguments as `class T, class... Ts` in order to do processing on the `T` and then recurse on the `Ts...` as was done above.

Comment: And then, you could take it a step further by basing the specialized types on [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) instead of defining the `value` member manually, eg: `template<> struct count<> : std::integral_constant<int, 0> {}; template<class T, class... Ts> struct count<T, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<int, 1 + count<Ts...>::value> {};`

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for recursion. All you need is a parameter pack and the `sizeof...` operator:

```
#include <iostream>


template<class... SS>
constexpr int count_template_params() {
    return sizeof...(SS);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "Count=" <<count_template_params<>() <<"\n";
    std::cout << "Count=" <<count_template_params<int>() <<"\n";
    std::cout << "Count=" <<count_template_params<int,int>() <<"\n";
    std::cout << "Count=" <<count_template_params<int,int,int>() <<"\n";
    std::cout << "Count=" <<count_template_params<int, int, int, int>() <<"\n";
    
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/ddPbnaaxq):

```
Count=0
Count=1
Count=2
Count=3
Count=4
```

Comment: OK, but that doesn't teach me anything about templates, which is really my goal here.  I want to know how to write recursive templates with zero-parameter base cases.

Comment: @jyelon it does teach you how to get the size of the parmeter pack, thats what you asked for

Comment: Fair enough. I'll try to devise a different example program that doesn't have such a simple solution.

Comment: @jyelon recursion is the old way. Its not needed anymore. At least from the top of the head I dont know an example taht still does need recursion

Comment: @jyelon fwiw the issue in your code without `DUMMY` is that `SS....` can be 0 up to n.